# Random sampling

Tags: probability, statistics

This is a very simple question, but I'm having a dilemma here.

Given a set (1, 2, 3, 4), find the sampling distribution of the mean S of sample of size 2.

1) Way 1:

Possible output are: 1.5 2 2.5(count 2 times) 3 3.5. Because we sample randomly (uniformly), $P(S=1.5)=1/6$
$P(S=2.5)=1/3$

2) Way 2:

$P(S=1.5)=P(X1=1,X2=2)+P(X1=2,X2=1)=2∗1/4∗1/4=1/8$

Which way is correct, 1 or 2? Please explain.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but isn't $P(S = 1.5)$ supposed to be $1/6$?

Comment: I think that's correct. Can you elaborate on it. Why is way 2 is incorrect?

Comment: As you stated, the possible outputs are $1.5, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 3.5$. Since you're sampling uniformly, the probability of having $1.5$ as a mean is $1/6$. $P(S = 1.5)$ is actually $1/2 P(S = 2.5)$ since there are 2 possibilities in which $2.5$ is the mean and 1 possibility in which $1.5$ is the mean. Way 2 should take into account the fact that $x2$ has 3 possibilities while $x1$ has 4 assuming that $x1 ≠ x2$. This means that it should be $2 * 1/4 * 1/3$ which yields $1/6$ just like Way 1.

Comment: Thank you all, it makes so much sense now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think my comment should've been an answer.

There are 6 possibilities:

- $mean(1, 2) = 1.5$
- $mean(1, 3) = 2$
- $mean(1, 4) = 2.5$
- $mean(2, 3) = 2.5$
- $mean(2, 4) = 3$
- $mean(3, 4) = 3.5$

$mean(x, y) = mean(y, x)$ allows us to disregard half the possibilities and we're going to disregard possibilities for $x1 = x2$.

This leaves us with 1 in 6 possibilities for the mean to be $1.5$.

Thus, $P(S = 1.5) = P(S = 2) = P(S = 3) = P(S = 3.5) = \frac{1}{6}$ and $P(S = 2.5) = \frac{1}{3}$

Way 2 was almost right. Correction: $P(S = 1.5) = 2 \times \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{3}$

Once a value for $x1$ is randomly picked, 3 numbers remain in the set to be chosen for $x2$, so each remaining number has a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of being selected. (Given that you're picking numbers uniformly)

Forgive my primitive wording.